# Ссылки при авторизации на сессиях

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт, стоит авторизация на сессиях, все работает, но иногда к ссылкам добавляется такой код `/index.php?PHPSESSID=9ebca8bd62c830d3e79272b4f585ff8f`. Думаю, многие с этим сталкивались. Как устранить такое?

Comment: Как Вы добились такого?)) Ничего подобного ни разу не было.

Answer (score 1):

```
ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 1);
```

Или выставить этот параметр сессий в `php.ini`.
Это нужно для использования только cookie в сессиях, тогда идентификатор сессий не будет вставляться в ссылки и формы, но если в браузере отключены cookie, то `session_start()` вызовет ошибку.
Можно это сделать, конечно, но это будет неверное решение. Если PHP не находит идентификатор сессии ни в куках, ни в `url`, то при `session_start()` пытается записать идентификатор сессии сразу и в ссылки на странице, и в куки, дабы посетитель не потерял сессию, если куки выключены.
Если Вы включите эту опцию, то придется требовать от посетителя включить куки.

Comment: Это единственный выход? Не знаешь же, кто твой посетитель : )

Comment: А это иногда выскакивает у уже авторизованного пользователя? Или у только что вошедшего на сайт?

Comment: Она выскакивает не 100%, но частенько, и выскакивает у всех.

Точнее все это после авторизации. Я делаю выход и вообще браузер закрываю, захожу по новой на сайт, и появляется сессия через гет передается.

Comment: Когда закрывается браузер, кука с идентификатором сессии удаляется, поэтому зайдя вновь на сайт, php не находит идентификатор сессии и пытается зависать новый идентификатор сразу и в куки и `url`. 
 
[session_set_cookie_params](php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).  
С помощью этой функции можно увеличить время жизни куки с идентификатором сессии.

Comment: Как ею воспользоватся ?) помоги, и смысл её время жизни продлевать если браузер удаляет сессию и куку  
--*--  
а все понял, по умолчанию кука хронится 0 сек, то есть при первом закрытии браузера